# How to Console.log elements of an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently console logging:

```
Array(2)
0: {id: '0p1a3', name: 'Ligue 1'}
1: {id: '0s7a9', name: 'La Liga'}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

I would just like to console log the name of each competition, i have tried

```
  let comps = this.state.competitions.name;
    console.log(comps)
```

Comment: what's the problem ?

Comment: @HritikSharma - They want to log just the names, not the full objects.

Comment: use a for loop, an console all the name of the each child element.

Comment: Or just `console.log(this.state.competitions.map(({name}) => name));`

Comment: for(let i=0 ; i<arr.length; i++)console.log(arr[i].name)

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to read through the available [array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). For this use-case [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) will be particularly useful. But knowing what's available to you will be invaluable to you going forward